# I'm having difficulty jumping to the correct section of a loop

Tags: java, loops, methods, calculation

What I'm trying to do is have the user enter a numerator and a denominator, and display the quotient. I'm using a method to check and see if the number is valid using Integer.parseInt and a try catch. The problem is that if the try catch catches the exception and displays the error, it continues to the next part of the code instead of jumping back to the beginning of the loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String numerator = "";
        String denominator = "";
        String message = "";
        int num = 0;
        int den = 0;
        int quo = 0;
        int yesNo = 0;
        do
        {
            // Displays a JOptionPane asking the user to input a numerator.
            numerator = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a numerator.", "Enter a Numerator",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            if(numerator == null)// This breaks the loop if  the user clicks the "cancel" button.
                break;
            num = IsValid(numerator); // Calls the IsValid method, passing it the String entered by the user to validate if it is a proper integer.
            denominator = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a denominator.", "Enter a Denominator",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            if(denominator == null) // same as above but for the denominator
                break;
            den = IsValid(denominator);
            /*if(den != 0 && num<den) 
            { // This section is unrelated to my problem
                quo = num/den;
                message = "Numerator: " + num + "\n" +
                            "Denominator: " + den + "\n" +
                            "Quotient: ";
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message,"Calculation",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }*/
            yesNo = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Would you like to make another calculation?","Continue?",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        }while(yesNo == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
    }
    public static int IsValid(String input)
    {
        int num = 0; // This method is passed the String that the JOptionPane receives and using Integer.parseInt to make sure it's an integer, and assigns it to int "num".
        try{num = Integer.parseInt(input);}
        catch(NumberFormatException ex)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Invalid number. Please enter a valid number.","Invalid Input",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
        return num;
        // My main issue is that it continues with the code instead of jumping back to the JOptionPane to ask the user for input a second time.
    }
```

Basically, I want to call IsValid(numerator) and assign it to the int "num", and if IsValid's catch statement is executed, jump back to the beginning of the do loop so it displays that JOptionPane again. If the catch statement is executed for the denominator, jump back to that one instead of the very beginning. I can't put the JOptionPane in the method because the method wouldn't be able to tell if I was sending it the numerator or the denominator. I'm fairly new to java and I'm certain there are easier ways to do this, so ANY help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Throw the exception from `isValid`, catch it and handle it in the loop

Comment: Yes, the problem is that you catch but don't propagate the exception.  You always just return in `int`.  Thus the higher level routine can't tell if the user typed something correct or not.  What you might consider is change `isValid` to a loop that does not exit until a valid number is entered.  Then you don't have to throw the exception and you also would be able to always return a valid number.

Comment: So like this?:
```
try{num = IsValid(numerator)}
catch(NumberFormatException ex){}
```
And then inside of the method, do:
```if(whatever)
{
       throw NumberFormatException;
}
``` 
Or am I completely wrong?

Comment: I would expect that a function named `IsValid` returns a boolean. You should call it `ParseNumber` or something similar.

Comment: My issue with using a loop inside the method is that the method can't determine if it is being sent a numerator or denominator, and has to say vague things like "Please enter a number" instead of being specific.

Comment: Pass a string as the argument to the method, where the string is the message you want the loop to display.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `isValid` should interrupt your program if the input is not valid. The most natural way is to let it throw an exception. 
Then your program catches the exception and exit.

```java
package so20190423;

import java.awt.HeadlessException;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Snippet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            String numerator = "";
            String denominator = "";
            String message = "";
            int num = 0;
            int den = 0;
            int quo = 0;
            int yesNo = 0;
            try {
                do
                {
                    // Displays a JOptionPane asking the user to input a numerator.
                    numerator = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a numerator.", "Enter a Numerator",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                    if(numerator == null)// This breaks the loop if  the user clicks the "cancel" button.
                        break;
                    num = IsValid(numerator); // Calls the IsValid method, passing it the String entered by the user to validate if it is a proper integer.
                    denominator = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a denominator.", "Enter a Denominator",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                    if(denominator == null) // same as above but for the denominator
                        break;
                    den = IsValid(denominator);
                    /*if(den != 0 && num<den) 
                    { // This section is unrelated to my problem
                        quo = num/den;
                        message = "Numerator: " + num + "\n" +
                                    "Denominator: " + den + "\n" +
                                    "Quotient: ";
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message,"Calculation",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    }*/
                    yesNo = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Would you like to make another calculation?","Continue?",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                }while(yesNo == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException ex)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Invalid number. Please enter a valid number.","Invalid Input",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
        public static int IsValid(String input) throws NumberFormatException
        {
            int num = 0; // This method is passed the String that the JOptionPane receives and using Integer.parseInt to make sure it's an integer, and assigns it to int "num".
            num = Integer.parseInt(input);
            return num;
            // My main issue is that it continues with the code instead of jumping back to the JOptionPane to ask the user for input a second time.
        }
}
```

You could even confine the try/catch in the while loop, to recover after a failed input and try again !

```java
package so20190423;

import java.awt.HeadlessException;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Snippet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            String numerator = "";
            String denominator = "";
            String message = "";
            int num = 0;
            int den = 0;
            int quo = 0;
            int yesNo = 0;
                do
                {
                    try {
                    // Displays a JOptionPane asking the user to input a numerator.
                    numerator = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a numerator.", "Enter a Numerator",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                    if(numerator == null)// This breaks the loop if  the user clicks the "cancel" button.
                        break;
                    num = IsValid(numerator); // Calls the IsValid method, passing it the String entered by the user to validate if it is a proper integer.
                    denominator = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a denominator.", "Enter a Denominator",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                    if(denominator == null) // same as above but for the denominator
                        break;
                    den = IsValid(denominator);
                    /*if(den != 0 && num<den) 
                    { // This section is unrelated to my problem
                        quo = num/den;
                        message = "Numerator: " + num + "\n" +
                                    "Denominator: " + den + "\n" +
                                    "Quotient: ";
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message,"Calculation",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    }*/
                    yesNo = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Would you like to make another calculation?","Continue?",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException ex)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Invalid number. Please enter a valid number.","Invalid Input",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                }
                }while(yesNo == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
        }
        public static int IsValid(String input) throws NumberFormatException
        {
            int num = 0; // This method is passed the String that the JOptionPane receives and using Integer.parseInt to make sure it's an integer, and assigns it to int "num".
            num = Integer.parseInt(input);
            return num;
            // My main issue is that it continues with the code instead of jumping back to the JOptionPane to ask the user for input a second time.
        }
}
```

Last variant, if you want to retry each input until it is valid (or cancelled by the user) :

```java
package so20190423;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Snippet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String numerator = "";
        String denominator = "";
        String message = "";
        int num = 0;
        int den = 0;
        int quo = 0;
        int yesNo = 0;
        do {
            boolean userCancelled = false;
            boolean numeratorIsOk = false;
            do {
                try {
                    numerator = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a numerator.", "Enter a Numerator",
                            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                    if (numerator == null) {
                        userCancelled = true;
                    } else {
                        num = IsValid(numerator);
                        numeratorIsOk = true;
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Invalid number. Please enter a valid number.",
                            "Invalid Input", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                }
            } while (!numeratorIsOk && !userCancelled);
            if (userCancelled) {
                break;
            }

            boolean denominatorIsOk = false;
            do {
                try {
                    denominator = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a denominator.",
                            "Enter a Denominator", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                    if (denominator == null) {
                        userCancelled = true;
                    } else {
                        den = IsValid(denominator);
                        denominatorIsOk = true;
                    }
                    /*
                     * if(den != 0 && num<den) { // This section is unrelated to my problem quo =
                     * num/den; message = "Numerator: " + num + "\n" + "Denominator: " + den + "\n"
                     * + "Quotient: "; JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                     * message,"Calculation",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); }
                     */
                    yesNo = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to make another calculation?",
                            "Continue?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Invalid number. Please enter a valid number.",
                            "Invalid Input", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                }

            } while (!denominatorIsOk && !userCancelled);
            if (userCancelled) {
                break;
            }
        } while (yesNo == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);

    }

    public static int IsValid(String input) throws NumberFormatException {
        int num = 0; // This method is passed the String that the JOptionPane receives and using
                        // Integer.parseInt to make sure it's an integer, and assigns it to int "num".
        num = Integer.parseInt(input);
        return num;
        // My main issue is that it continues with the code instead of jumping back to
        // the JOptionPane to ask the user for input a second time.
    }
}
```

HTH!

Comment: My issue is that this would jump back to the beginning of the loop rather than the part of the loop where the error occurs, ie if the user enters an invalid denominator, it would make them re-enter the numerator to get a valid denominator. I want it to jump to the denominator if the denominator is the issue.

Comment: @coreynj then use two try/catch statements, one for each call to `isValid`, and add a do-while loop that reruns the try/isValid until it's OK...  See my updated answer !